# Texstudio and subfiles package

Tags: texstudio, subfiles

I am using TexStudio and am very happy with it. Now I have discovered the subfiles package to be able to compile only the part of my document I am working on.
But TexStudio detects that the document is inputted into my main document and compiles the main document instead.

My current workaround is to set the subfile as current master document, but that is quite clumsy. I have not found any option to turn off the automatic master mode in TexStudio, did I overlook something?

Comment: wild guess since I'm not familiar with TeXStudio: couldn't you just comment out from the main file the `\subfile` commands you don't want to include in compilation and then compile the main file as usual?

Comment: Well, that would be a workaround as well, because then I have to take care that I reinclude it into the main file. What I want is just to compile the currently active tab and remove TexStudios intelligence.

Comment: Another option would be using the `% !TeX root` magic comment. See http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION31 (section "4.1.1 Root Document" as of writing).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour in my TeXStudio installation. Compiling only the subfile works fine for me.

Comment: @kdb Awesome!    -