# In TeXstudio, how to compile only the subfile?

Tags: texstudio, subfiles

There exist several questions along the same line as mine here, but none of them have been answered:
[How do I compile standalone files in TeXStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/how-do-i-compile-standalone-files-in-texstudio)
[Texstudio and subfiles package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148680/texstudio-and-subfiles-package)
[Problems when compiling subfiles (with the subfiles package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430363/problems-when-compiling-subfiles-with-the-subfiles-package)

How do I get only my subfile to compile in TeXstudio once it has detected what the root file is. Currently, it will always compile the root file, instead of just the subfile, which takes away the actual function of the subfiles package! Annoying!

Comment: You can just compile the file with the `standalone` class. In TeXstudio select the tab of this file and press the compile button (or F6) Is this what you want?

Comment: you can use the magic comment `%! TeX root: sub` if your subfile name is `sub.tex`, then if you press compile while you're in `sub.tex`, it will compile the subfile instead of the main file.

Comment: None of these suggestions work in TeXstudio it seems, at least not once a root file has been picked already. I can change the root file manually by clicking on "Options->Root Document->Set root document explicitly" to the one I want to compile right then and there, which is a bit excessive when jumping around between files/documents. @faltfe

Comment: @pi223871 I always used the automatic detection of the root file so far. That's probably the reason why there is no problem with jumping between different files for me.
But if you change a subfile why wouldn't you change the main file as well, when it includes the subfile?

Comment: @faltfe The reason is the computing time it takes for the whole document to come through. Sometimes I just want make small changes, like resizing an image and then I need the document to compile fast. In those cases I want to finish editing the subfile first, before I go back to the root file to compile the whole document again. As I understand it, that was the main functionality of the subfiles package, only that it doesn't work with TeXstudio right now. I wish I could turn off the root file feature clean and easy.

Comment: @pi223871 I think you don't mean a standalone. Could it be, that you only use a seccond .tex file without `\documentclass{standalone}` and includes it into the main document with `\include{filename}`. Maybe you can show us a minimal example of the file you want to compile.

Comment: @pi223871 One workaround can be to compile the `subfile` via the terminal. Go to `Tools` -> `Open Terminal` and run `pdflatex mysubfile`. Maybe, one can write a macro for this.
At first I thought you are using the `standalone` class because you linked it. But as @Ahrtaler mentioned you probably don't and use the `subfiles` package instead.

Comment: @faltfe Yes, I am using the subfile package, not the standalone package. However, in the linked question the issue seems to be the same with the standalone package. Your example below is exactly what I have, I shall give it a try!

Comment: @pi223871 Which version of TeXstudio do you have? Magic comments at the start of the document like `% !TeX root = subfilename.tex` work fine for me.

Comment: @pi223871 sorry, typo in my original comment. there shouldnt be a space between %! and TeX

Comment: @samcarter That did the trick! I saw this command in so many places but never noticed the discrepancy. I updated to 2.12.10 in the process of finding a solution.

Comment: @Troy No worries, we did find out eventually. :D

Comment: @Troy Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a magic comment called `%!TeX root` at the beginning of your `subfile.tex` to override the default root detection by TXS. This way, when you are in `subfile.tex` and press compile, TXS will treat `subfile.tex` as root and compile that instead of `main.tex`, as required.

As an example, it might look something like:

**subfile.tex**

```
%!TeX root = subfile
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    Hello world.
\end{document}
```

This was also covered in the [TXS user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION31).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer! Off-topic: As you are our resident texstudio expert, do you know where `%BEGIN_FOLD` and `%END_FOLD` are documented? I was asked this in a comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450793/wrapping-preamble-in-texstudio#comment1133250_450794 but could not answer. I searched the texstudio user manual, but cannot find it there.

Comment: @samcarter It's defined in `tex.qnfa`, it's alluded to in the user manual, but not explicitly documented (that code folding is controlled by qnfa files).  see [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/5e45554eeabee2f6e39aa9a29b75ebc38d6fb156/utilities/qxs/tex.qnfa#L9); also lines 23 and 24.

Comment: Fantastic! This is very helpful - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is some kind of *workaround* one can use. You can write a small macro to run a single file using the `subfiles` class in TeXstudio. Actually it the macro doesn't care about the documentclass.

Suppose you have the following two files `main-document.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  My main file text.
  \subfile{subfile-document}
\end{document}
```

and `subfile-document.tex`

```
\documentclass[main-document.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    Some subfile text
\end{document}
```

Now you can define a macro in TeXstudio using [Script](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33).

```
%SCRIPT
var filename = app.getCurrentFileName();
var dir = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("/"));
var proc = system("pdflatex " + filename, dir);
```

The macro does the following:

- Get the current select filename
- Extract the directory path
- Call `pdflatex <filename>` inside the `cmd` and passes the correkt directory to the command line

TeXstudio uses keybindings for macros by default <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> but you are able to remap them. The number of the <kbd>Fx</kbd> key depend on the number of macros you have defined.

Now you can run the only the subfile by

1. Select the `subfile-document.tex` tab
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to run the macro. (TeXstudio might ask you for futherer privileges)

**EDIT:** I've created an issue asking about how to load a pdf file using a macro script on [https://github.com/texstudio-org/](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/319)

**EDIT 2** You can use this updated script to display the built pdf using the inbuilt pdf viewer.

```
%SCRIPT

function quote(filename){
    return '"' + filename + '"';
}

var filename = app.getCurrentFileName();
var dir = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("/"));
var pdflatexcmd = '../MikTex/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe  -src -interaction=nonstopmode '
var proc = system(pdflatexcmd + quote(filename), dir);
proc.waitForFinished();

var pdfFilename = quote(filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ".pdf"));

app.runInternalCommand("txs:///view-pdf-internal" , "--embedded", pdfFilename);
```

Comment: Ok, this works, it compiles the file! Now I need another command in the macro so that the pdf shows up in the pdf-viewer in TeXstudio. Just pressing F7 will pull up the last document compiled by TeXstudio itself. Any ideas?

Comment: For the moment I just could find the object `pdfs` in the docs which lists all opened pdf viewers. But I can't manage to show the created pdf so far.