# Wrapping preamble in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, preamble

Texstudio offers the handy option to wrap the code corresponding to whole sections, environments, etc.

**Is there a way to the same with a documents' preamble?**

I have tried embedding the whole preamble into curly braces `{ whole preamble }`, stopping right before `\begin{document}`. That allows me to wrap the preamble, but it generates and error when compiling.

Also, I know I could export the preamble to another document and use `\include` or `\input`, but I am specifically looking for a solution that keeps the whole document unified, with the actual preamble at the top (but "wrappable" in the editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
%BEGIN_FOLD

your preamble

%END_FOLD
```

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden You're welcome!

Comment: May I know where I can find more of these tweaks in the manual?

Comment: @Diaa I can't even find this one in the user guide. So I don't know if there are more of them.

Comment: @Diaa I just asked our texstudio expert about this, please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450546/in-texstudio-how-to-compile-only-the-subfile/451000?noredirect=1#comment1133649_451000 for the reply.

Comment: @samcarter many thanks for sharing this with me :)